# Integration matrix

Tags: integration, summation, transformation, matrix-calculus, discrete-calculus

I want to do integration(summation) of a signal(x) using matrix multiplication.

I am looking for a transformation matrix, *I* corresponding to integration such that

*F = I* * *x* ,  where *x* is the signal vector and *F* is the integral.

I tried implementing integral using a matrix *I* where *I(i,:)*(ith row of *I*) is all *1* s till ith column and *0* s after that. This gives the *i*th value of integral *F* as the sum of the 1st *i* values of *x* .  Is it the correct way to do it.

Problem is that if my *x* is *sine* function from 0 to 10(rad) the integral should be *-cos* (my assumption). But by this method, my 1st value will be *0* , which is not correct.

Comment: $\int_0^x \sin t dt = \color{red}{1} - \cos x$.

Comment: @achillehui   So when we integrate a vector(discrete signal) using matrix multiplication, is it assumed that the integral is definite integral from 0th sample to ith sample

Comment: Yes. that is equivalent to a definite integral.